# how to call actionscript function from javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I have a function like this in actionscript3

```
private function uploadFile(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var uploader:URLRequest = new URLRequest(serverUploadFile);
            localFile.upload(uploader);
        }
```

how can i call this function from javascript ?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AS3 Use ExternalInterface to add a javascript callback.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("uploadFile", null, uploadFile);
```

More details [here](http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/08/16/external-interface/)

Comment: this seems very practical, i should try

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property uploadFile. i am getting this error, sorry i am very new in actionscript

Answer (score 1):

Use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary)