# Calling Js function in a .js file from action script file

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

Is there any way to call Js function in a .js file from action script file (Here, I mean a "stand alone" .js file, not a js file embedded in html tag)

Suppose I have a file **lib.js**, and inside it, I have two function **hello(str)** and **bye(str)**.

Now, I want my function **sayHello(str)** in my Calculator.as class be able to do something like that:

```
function sayHello(str:String) : void {
    hello(str)
    ...........
    ...........
    bye(str)
}
```

It's possible to have such function like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExternalInterface.call to call javascript functions.

Comment: But It must be located inside a Html tag, isn't it ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674402/how-to-call-actionscript-function-from-javascript

Comment: The javascript code has to be in your html page inside a script tag, or included from an external js file, again with a script tag.
<script type="text/javascript"> js code here </script>

Comment: Is there any way to use it without Html tag, I mean call a function from .js file from .as file ? I want to do that because I have a lib written in .js file.

Answer (score 1):

If the JS file is loaded into the site with the flash, you can use `ExternalInterface.call("hello", str)` to call it.

Comment: Here, I don't use flash, but air. In fact, I have a .as file, I also have a .js library written before. Now, I don't want to rewrite my lib in as3, but directly use it.

Comment: Not that I know. There is no JS-interpreter built into the flash runtime. It might be possible to load a HTML page into the Air app, and connect through that (through some native browser), but I think it'll be easier to simply convert the JS code to AS3...

Comment: You mean that I will create a HTLM file, then, have something like that <script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"> </script>. Finally, Load this HTML file with action script 3. At that time, I will be able to use js function, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try with this one http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_02.html

Comment: Can you specify it a little more ?

Comment: It is a class/component which can load html content. In theory you can put your javascript there and try if it will work.