# Stop flash video in WebKit using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, webkit

I would like to stop a flash video (if it is running) in WebKit browser.

I thought I could perhaps use JavaScript to do that, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should set up an ExternalInterface in your Flash video and use that to communicate between JavaScript and AS3.

See here:
[how to call actionscript function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674402/how-to-call-actionscript-function-from-javascript)

Comment: It is not "my" video. I am on a YouTube page. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, it does. Since you won't be able to modify the source code for YouTube in any way you can't create your own ExternalInterface. There is, however an API available for YouTube videos that you can find here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=nl